# PHP Mongodb installation issue on Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa

Tags: php, mongodb, composer-php, linux-mint

I am new to mongodb ,

I am following one tutorial and proceeding  step by step , I installed mongodb and access it from shell .

Then I am doing php mongodb installation part .
I am doing it through composer , install composer and run the below command

```html
composer require mongodb/mongodb
```

I am getting this below error output in my terminal .

```html
$ composer require mongodb/mongodb
Using version ^1.4 for mongodb/mongodb
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.4.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.4.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.4.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for mongodb/mongodb ^1.4 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
```

Here I added this things to my php.ini file and restarted the apache file.

extension = mongodb.so

PHP VERSION - PHP 5.5.9  AND Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa

Any suggestion?
where I am doing wrong

Comment: does `php -m` show you that the php mongodb extension is installed?

Comment: mbstring
mhash
mysql
mysqli


'M' letter contains this many output only

Comment: then you need to install the mongodb drivers for php: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-the-mongodb-php-driver-extension-on-centos-6/ the command `pecl install mongo` is probably missing for you